# Audio/Video Remote Control Profile (AVRCP) on Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile

Is there a general way to handle Bluetooth [Audio/Video Remote Control Profile (AVRCP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Audio.2FVideo_Remote_Control_Profile_.28AVRCP.29) events on a WM device? I'm especially interested in a Compact Framework way, but I would be happy with just a simple P/Invoke API.

**Update.**
I've read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909962.aspx) articles on this topic, but I still have no idea on how to facilitate this knowledge. There are no samples. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the MSDN page about [AVRCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa916569.aspx)

Microsofts solution uses the Audio/Video Control Transport Control Protocol (AVCTP). The Microsoft component is an extension layer to the L2CAP layer in the [Microsoft Bluetooth Protocol Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909962.aspx).

The following list shows the supported commands:

- Play
- Stop
- Pause
- Forward
- Backward

[Other Bluetooth profiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915866.aspx) can be found on MSDN as well.

Hope this helps